# amChart Grafico simple de lineas ! Por favor ayuda

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, amcharts

Tengo una base de datos MySql con una tabla la cual tiene varias columnas, entre ellas la fecha y la hora. El resto son columnas de valores como temperatura.

Necesito simplemente hacer un gráfico lineal con la fecha/hora combinadas en el eje horizontal y los valores en el vertical.

```js
        <script>
            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "data.php"
  },
  "graphs": [ {
    "valueField": "temperatura",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "lineThickness ": 2,
    "lineAlpha": 0.5
  } ],"pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/",
  "categoryField": "fecha",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "rotate": true,
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true
  }
} );

 "dataUpdated" event
        </script>
```

Lo que estoy logrando es popular el gráfico con data pero los ejes me quedan invertidos (vertical para fecha). Estoy usando sólo la fecha, después tendría que agregar la hora también.

Millon de gracias al que pueda ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a quitar el `"rotate": true,` estando a `true` lo que hace es invertir los ejes